# Which library in Visual C# for graphics programming, Tao or OpenTK?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, tao-framework

I heard that newest OpenGL does not have glBegin anymore. In other words things change a lot, and I was wondering which library should I use for OpenGL programming in c#?

I will do graphics programming for a CAD modeling application.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think Tao is even maintained with any regularity.  I'd suggest OpenTK.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in some of the comments, the Tao Framework has not been actively developed since 2008. However, I believe there is still some merit in using the framework. For example, the [C# Game Programming: For Serious Game Creation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435455568) book used the Tao framework for it's sample project (built in stages through the entire book). This is in spite of the book being published in mid 2010. Still, OpenTK will continue to evolve, so it is probably the better route if you want to stay on top of new features.

PS - The book was a great read in my opinion.

Comment: What do you think about developing on Linux? The mesa library is active.

Comment: @pokoko222: I've never done development for Linux (aside from some python and scheme), so I can only offer advice that a Google search would turn up. Maybe take a look at this answer over on the gamedev stack exchange for some ideas: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-c-libraries-can-be-used-to-support-game-development/226#226

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend OpenTK for OpenGL development using C#.

You are correct that the new versions of OpenGL (version 3 and 4) support a shader-based approach to rendering, and this is encouraged as the "forward compatible" path for all new OpenGL development.

That said, you can initialize OpenGL with either a "core" (shader-based) or "compatible" (old-style) profile on startup.  The compatible profile supports the classic OpenGL fixed-pipeline programming API.

You can review more [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides)

Answer (score 0):

Tao framework might be useful and handy to you.
see also a tutorial here: 
http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/using-opengl-in-c-taoframework/

Comment: But the last release is 2008, isn't it risky to use Tao?

Comment: Not at all. You are feel to use it in VS2010. Also try the latest Tao framework. The tutorial just outlines the steps, you still need OpenGL knowledge in your project

Comment: If Tao was last released in 2008, then it doesn't have support for anything in OpenGL since then. It might be OK for a CAD modeller, but nothing much more than that.

Comment: What should I be using If I wanted more than that? Maybe not now, maybe not after a year, but after that I probably would. Maybe Mono on linux and Mesa or something?

Comment: You have pretty much 3 choices: Tao, OpenTK, or writing your own GL bindings. You've decided that Tao isn't appropriate, so that narrows it down to OpenTK or doing it yourself.